# setInterval on resize

Tags: javascript, resize, setinterval

I have the below code:

```
    var intervalId = "";
    var isRunning = false;
    var iCount = 0;

    function animation() {
        switch (iCount++ % 2) {
            case 0:
                $('.class1').removeClass("is-active");
                $(".class2").addClass("is-active");
                break;
            case 1:
                $('.class2').removeClass("is-active");
                $(".class1").addClass("is-active");
                break;
        }
        isRunning = true;
    }

    if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
        intervalId = setInterval(animation, 3000);
    }

    $(window).on("orientationchange resize", function () {

        debounce(function () {
            if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
                if (isRunning == true) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            } else if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
                if (isRunning == false) {
                    intervalId = setInterval(animation, 3000);
                }
            }
        }, 250);
    });
```

What I'm trying to get, is on a 1024+ screen the `setInterval` is fired, anything below 1024 isn't fired. But on resize to lower than 1024 the `setInterval` still being fired.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using this code for my resize function.

```
    $(window).on("orientationchange resize", debounce(function () {
        if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = "";
        } else {
            if (!intervalId) intervalId = setInterval(animation, 3000);
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isRunning` logic is useless and redundant with `intervalId` being defined or not. You're using two variables for the same thing, and that's overkill.

Besides, you test `window.innerWidth` twice : is it <1024 or is it >1024 ? The second test is useless, and what happens if it's *exactly* 1024?

This block code makes things clearer and simpler :

```
debounce(function () {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
       clearInterval(intervalId);
    } else {
       if(!intervalId) intervalId = setInterval(animation, 3000);
    }
})
```